# Androidx workmanager inject with dagger

Tags: dagger, android-workmanager, androidx

I am exploring Work manager.

But I try to inject with dagger 2.15

I follow this [guideline](https://gist.github.com/ferrerojosh/82bd92748f315155fa6a842f4ed64c82)

but the problem is DispatchingAndroidInjector is not injecting on Application class.
I got this kind of error.

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property workerInjector has not been initialized
```

code

```
@Inject
lateinit var workerInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Worker>

override fun workerInjector() = workerInjector
```

I don't find any solution to fix.
If you have other working methods then please share. I stuck on this problem

Comment: Hi @Shudipto, Did you get this done?

Comment: Yes, at that time I move to KOIN. Now I use koin. I think koin is easier than dagger and require less code to config than dagger

Comment: please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53996415/1243318

Comment: Hey, actually I found koin is handier than the dagger, less code to write and so on. So I use koin

Answer (score 0):

A complete step by step guide (and a sample project) can be found here
https://github.com/raiytu4/dagger-workmanager 
Follow that guide, you can able to do something like this:

```
class HelloWorldWorker @Inject constructor(
    private val params: WorkerParameters,
    private val appContext: Context,
    private val foo: Foo // test dependence
    // add more dependencies here
) : Worker(appContext, params)
```