# CoroutineWorker doesn't start

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried to run the job, but I get one error all the time. code:

```
    class UpdaterJob @Inject constructor(
    private val context: Context,
      workerParams: WorkerParameters
) :
    CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result = //coroutineScope {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            Result.success()
            //  }
        }


    companion object {
        const val TAG = "UpdateChecker"

        fun setupTask(context: Context) {
            val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .build()

            val request = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<UpdaterJob>(
                1, TimeUnit.DAYS,
                1, TimeUnit.HOURS
            )
                .addTag(TAG)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .build()


            //  WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(request)

            WorkManager.getInstance(context)
                .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(TAG, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, request)
        }

        fun cancelTask(context: Context) {
            WorkManager.getInstance(context).cancelAllWorkByTag(TAG)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to make my DaggerWorkerFactory, by [Dagger2: Unable to inject dependencies in WorkManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52434165/dagger2-unable-to-inject-dependencies-in-workmanager) , but I still get one and the same error, log:

> 2021-02-02 13:39:15.894 7542-7542/com.rulate.rulateapp.debug
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:
> com.rulate.rulateapp.debug, PID: 7542 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> Failed resolution of:
> Landroidx/work/impl/utils/futures/AbstractFuture;
> at androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerImpl.initialize(WorkManagerImpl.java:181)
> at androidx.work.WorkManager.initialize(WorkManager.java:210)
> at com.rulater.rulateapp.ui.App.configureWorkManager(App.kt:60)
> at com.rulater.rulateapp.ui.App.onCreate(App.kt:47)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1192)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6712)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture
> at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
> at androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerImpl.initialize(WorkManagerImpl.java:181) 
> at androidx.work.WorkManager.initialize(WorkManager.java:210) 
> at com.rulater.rulateapp.ui.App.configureWorkManager(App.kt:60) 
> at com.rulater.rulateapp.ui.App.onCreate(App.kt:47) 
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1192) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6712) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
> Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;
> at androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerImpl.initialize(WorkManagerImpl.java:181) 
> at androidx.work.WorkManager.initialize(WorkManager.java:210) 
> at com.rulater.rulateapp.ui.App.configureWorkManager(App.kt:60) 
> at com.rulater.rulateapp.ui.App.onCreate(App.kt:47) 
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1192) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6712) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
> "com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture" on path:
> DexPathList[[zip file
> "/data/app/~~hUB4V6hTR0qg-4tdmVBeBg==/com.rulate.rulateapp.debug-qn72fwjfGyiwIXEoVyVyTw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~hUB4V6hTR0qg-4tdmVBeBg==/com.rulate.rulateapp.debug-qn72fwjfGyiwIXEoVyVyTw==/lib/x86,
> /data/app/~~hUB4V6hTR0qg-4tdmVBeBg==/com.rulate.rulateapp.debug-qn72fwjfGyiwIXEoVyVyTw==/base.apk!/lib/x86,
> /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
> at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
> at androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerImpl.initialize(WorkManagerImpl.java:181) 
> at androidx.work.WorkManager.initialize(WorkManager.java:210) 
> at com.rulater.rulateapp.ui.App.configureWorkManager(App.kt:60) 
> at com.rulater.rulateapp.ui.App.onCreate(App.kt:47) 
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1192) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6712) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly adding guava to your `build.gradle` dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.2-android'
```

Comment: The error is gone, but it still doesn't work (

Comment: Can you check with just `enqueue()` and create an `init {  /* Logs */  }` to check if the worker is creeated

Comment: I'm a little confused about what needs to be done. After checking with the debugger, the setup Task function is triggered, but DoWork does not start